# Drupal 7 Image style with cck field

Tags: 7, media

I upgraded my drupal site from drupal 6 to drupal 7, and imported the image cache presets to image style.

When I checked in the styles folder of drupal files, no images where created with the effects of image style module.

I change the cck image field of a content type under "Manage Display", and have set the option to of Image style to "tiny" which is Image style I have defined (scale:100px).

Yet when I try to access the node, Images with big sizes gets loaded along with the content.

I am still struggling to find a way to display cck image field to show images having the respective Image Style to it.

Also I am running the site in windows xampp.

Comment: Check your presets. They may not have imported properly. You should also check for any error messages.

Comment: I tried rebuilding the image style by using the flush functionality...still it shows me old big images...how to make it work?

Comment: Go to _/admin/config/media/image-styles_ and check your presets. They may all be now set to the "old big images". You may have to redefine them one by one.

Comment: I checked it. They are having all the effects like scale , resize which used to be there in drupal 6 image cache presets. Even I tried editing them each one of them so that all the images get regenerated in the respective styles folder. But still there are only empty folders for each style .